# Adventurer's salary

Tags: dnd-5e, economy

I'm trying to calculate how much gold adventurer's are supossed to earn each day. Unfortunately I can't find an answer on the books. The closer thing I found is the treasure hoards rewards for a full campaign, or the adjusted xp earned per day, but those are far from perfect.

The reason is that I'm running a campaign with a bunch of npc's contractors, but I want a solid way to calculate payments.

Comment: Actually I found that the answer of @nitsua60 at http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72202/whats-a-good-pay-rate-per-level-for-a-party-for-hire answer my question. I was looking for a level 1 to level 20 / Gp / day table actually.

Answer (score 6):

### There's no rule for adventurers, but skilled hirelings get 2gp/day

There is no rule in 5e for an adventurer's daily salary. You could likely calculate something based on how much PC's are expected to bring in at a given level for an average day in the dungeon but, as you already realized, it's far from perfect.

So what is there? PHB p.159 gives a list of services PCs can purchase that includes skilled hirelings for 2gp/day. The paragraph above gives the example of, "Mercenary soldiers paid to help the adventures take on a hobgoblin army are hirelings", so apparently skilled hirelings will go in to battle for you.

For comparison a comfortable life style costs 2gp/day so the hirelings are reasonably well off assuming they are working more often than not.

Comment: As a side note, if the hirelings are really working more often than not, they are probably dead by now. :P

Comment: @Zachiel "Tell me more about your retirement plan..."