# Are there any recommended weights, costs, or lead times for siege weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, published-adventures, forgotten-realms, storm-kings-thunder

The party that I'm the DM for recently got use of an airship, which came with a ballista and harpoon. The first thing that one of the party members wanted to do was purchase even more siege weapons to use on it. Well, that's fine, and it's helpful to find something for the characters do with with all that wealth they have walking around.

However, while the DMG lists several siege weapons and how much damage they can do, there isn't any indication of how much they might cost, how long it might take to have them built, or how much they weigh. I can certainly just make up some numbers, but it'd be really helpful to have a starting point. Is there any standard recommendations for weight, cost, and lead time for siege weapons? Maybe something listed in some other published adventure, or based on similar items elsewhere?

If setting matters, this is part of a *Storm King's Thunder* campaign in the Forgotten Realms.

Answer (score 2):

The *Spelljammer* campaign setting (AD&D 2e) is centered around Airship combat/adventures. It lists cost for weapons and number of weapons allowed based on ship size/type.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any official conversion to 5e; however, a search will bring up many unofficial conversions.

Comment: In my experience--which you're free to cite or not as you see fit--cost conversions from 2e to 5e have been fine played one-to-one. (Treasure I discount by 1/10 when running 2e stuff in 5e, though. I.e. 2e gives out much more cash than 5e expects, but costs feel similar enough to leave alone.) See https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/72209/23970 and https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/104964/23970 for examples.