# Can siege weapons from the DMG be purchased in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, dnd-adventurers-league

In D&D 5e Adventurers League, can the siege weapons as seen in the DMG be purchased?

Comment: Related and possible dupe on [siege weapon weights, lead times, and costs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134614/are-there-any-recommended-weights-costs-or-lead-times-for-siege-weapons)

Comment: Related. The Adventurer's League aspect does mean it would have a different answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No, you cannot buy siege engines in AL (currently).

(This writing is as of the [Adventurers League Player's Guide v8.2](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/ALPGv82.pdf).)

Part 1 of the ALPG includes **equipment at character creation** in Step 5; this refers you to items "the resources listed in Step 1 & 2," none of which are the DMG (or contain siege engines like those in the DMG).

Part 2 of the ALPG describes rewards and equipment separately. **Equipment** can only be bought/sold **between sessions** as in character creation: from the books that don't include siege engines. **During play** equipment can only be bought as laid out in individual adventures; I've not seen any that allow the purchase of siege equipment yet. (Though I've not run *all* of the AL adventures: if some enterprising reader knows of one and can point me to it I'll gladly delete this answer and bounty theirs whatever votes this had!)

**Rewards** include *treasure (check)points*, which can buy you magic items from tables A-I in the DMG, subject to tier limitations. We're a *little* closer to siege equipment, but not there, sadly.

Unless you think a *horn of blasting* counts. It worked for Joshua, after all.